# How can I edit the Menu entries in the taskbar?

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar

I am running Lubuntu 18.04LTS and have a taskbar at the bottom of the screen.  The leftmost button opens a menu of themed options, such as "Graphics" with subfolders of applications (GIMP, Inkscape, Krita, Digicam, and so on).  I've got an entry for Digikam that currently points to an older version than the one I recently downloaded.  I know I can make a shortcut on the desktop to that but I'd really like to just edit the file that tells the entries which to open.  Can I do that somehow?  Thank you!

Comment: In my first days of Ubuntu I tried to edit the Application menu. But, later I found out that this is an unnecessary waste of time. Things in Gnome do not work like in Windows. However, if you still want to edit it; see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3

Comment: Thank you!  This was useful!  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did this myself.

I found the file I needed by right clicking on the existing menu item and choosing "Properties."

From there, it points to a .desktop file (mine was in /usr/share/applications, as I suspect most of them are...)

I edited that with "sudo emacs" and added the different path to the application.

Save the file and it opens the new one perfectly.

In doing this, I noticed that the exec was simply "digikam" so perhaps a better way would be to have pointed whatever file "digikam" was linked to to the new location?

If anyone wishes to tell me the proper way to do this, that'd be great.  But at this point at least my way worked.  :-)

Comment: Editing files which are shipped with deb-packages is a **bad idea**. They will be overwritten on next package upgrade. You should copy the "problematic" file to your local application folder (`~/.local/share/applications`) and change it here. Or use GUI tools like `alacarte` or `mozo`.