# How to unlist apps

Tags: apt, wine, 19.10, menu

recently i uninstalled some wine programs and they are still listed in the list of applications. Needless to say that because they are uninstalled they give error when I try to open them

Comment: Welcome! Tell me if you can find these apps with this command: `find /usr/share/applications -name "*the name of your app*"`.

Comment: That command don't gave me any output

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to applications in the menu entry, try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/891286/616827) answer.

Installing `alacarte` gave you the ability to edit the shortcuts in the menu. You can also add custom applications and even change the icon. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Here]

To install, type in terminal:

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

Comment: Thanks, i deleted some shortcuts but there are some that don't appear on alacarte and still there

Comment: then you'll need a manual way. is it okay for you? what desktop environment are you using? @Ivanghi