# How can I remove the Additional Drivers application present within the Applications Menu

Tags: uninstall, appmenu, software-uninstall, cleanup

My machine requires no additional drivers, however I cannot remove this application [**additional drivers**] neither did I install it.

I tried the following: Removing it via the Ubuntu Software center, but there is only the option to install it.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can remove it.

[image]

Comment: Which desktop are you using? https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3

Comment: @SHawarden 
HP ProDesk 600 G2 Desktop Mini
Running: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / Linux 5.4.0-40-generic

Comment: Sorry, which desktop environment are you using? Cinnamon? Gnome? Unity? The link has a 3rd party app that works with several, and some have built in menu editing abilities.

Comment: It is one of those programs that cause more trouble removing than leaving alone.  If you don't need it, it does nothing, except having a small icon around.

Comment: @SHawarden: Desktop Environment - GNOME

Answer (score 1):

The application you are showing in your screenshot is for `software-properties-qt`. This is a qt interface of software properties for the KDE desktop. It is not installed by default, as opposed to the gtk-version, `software-properties-gtk`. It is not that one that is providing your "Additional Drivers" icon in the menu.

The "Additional Drivers" menu item actually opens a specific tab of the  "Software & Updates" application (`software-properties-gtk`). You can only remove that tab by removing the entire application. Doing so will remove all functionality of that app, i.e., a graphical tool to interact with your software sources, change update settings etc. It will also remove the Gnome software center (although not the Snap Store in Ubuntu 20.04). It will remove the automatic graphical updater. Accordingly, although you can remove it, you could only continue to manage your software through the terminal if you remove software-properties-gtk.

You may be fine by just removing the "Additional drivers" menu item.

**Removing "Additional drivers" from your application menu**

Copy the `.desktop`file `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-drivers.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`. Open the local copy in your text editor and a line `Hidden=true`. This will remove the icon for "Additional drivers" from your user menu/application overview.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standalone application, so removing it is unwise.

- The UI is part of the `software-properties-gtk` package. DON'T remove that. If you are not skilled with apt config files, then you need it.
- The list of drivers is provided by the `ubuntu-drivers-common` package. You can remove it, but that will just generate errors when software-properties-gtk cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$ cd /usr/share/applications

$ sudo mv software-properties-drivers.desktop software-properties-drivers.desktop.hidden